# Error in installing the C# Windows Application build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, windows

I have created a C# Windows Application project build and selected Prerequisites as Microsoft .net framework 4.5(x86 and x64), Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime, Microsoft System CLR Types for Sql Server 2012 (x64) and selected the option Download Prerequisites from the same location as my application.The build is created successfully.

But when i try to install the build in Client computer the following error message occurs "An error occurred while installing system components for 'Application name' setup cannot continue until all system components have been successfully installed ". 
When i checked the install file it says - Verifying file integrity of ReportViewer.msi. WinVerifyTrust returned -2146762486. file not trusted

The Application installs without any problem if i connect to internet and install the application. But i want it to work without internet connection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because dependencies are not installed on target machine and an active connection is required to do that so. Are you creating setup using ClickOnce ?

Comment: @AdnanUmer thanks for the reply. I am building the project using publish now option.

Comment: Might that helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188132/clickonce-deploy-on-dvd-with-offline-installer